# Scraping Latitude and Longitude from Tripadvisor

Tags: r

I wanted to scrape the latitude and longitude from TripAdvisor. But I get an error. Same happens when trying to do the same with the Hotel Class.

```
enter code here
url2 <- "https://www.tripadvisor.es/Hotel_Review-g187499-d239247-Reviews-Melia_Girona-Girona_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html"
TripHotel<-read_html(url2)

Coordenadas <- TripHotel %>%
  html_node("substring-after(substring-before(substring-before(substring-after(normalize-space(//script[contains(.,'lat: ')]), '= {'), ', zoom:'), ','), 'lat: ')") %>%
  html_text()
Coordenadas

Estrellas <- TripHotel %>%
  html_nodes("_2TmwtWEr _30WZSV_9 uq1qMUbD") %>%
  html_text()
Estrellas
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @GregorThomas I attach you the image on the post